# mqtt bridge config for OUT / IN topic filter

Tags: mqtt, iot, raspbian

I am trying to setup MQTT bridge to cloudmqtt.com. Local bridge running on raspbian.

I want to push local topics (`UP/site1/#`) to cloudmqtt broker as it is & pull remote topics ('Down/site1/#') to local bridge.
Tried following configs, but didn't work

1. `topic UP/site1/# out 2`

   `topic Down/site1/# in 2`
2. `topic UP/site1/# out 2 UP/site1/ UP/site1/`

   `topic Down/site1/# in 2 Down/site1/ Down/site1/`
3. `topic UP/site1/# out 2 "" ""`

   `topic Down/site1/# in 2 "" ""`

Here is the full config

```
connection cloudmqtt
address *****.cloudmqtt.com:1883
bridge_protocol_version mqttv311
remote_username ****
remote_password ****
try_private false
start_type automatic
notifications false
cleansession false
topic UP/site1/# out 2
topic Down/site1/# in 2
```

Bridge log messages :

```
1545695073: Received PINGREQ from 8de7c6e8-4c6a-49b0-9aaa-5816aa9504901545604132782
1545695073: Sending PINGRESP to 8de7c6e8-4c6a-49b0-9aaa-5816aa9504901545604132782
1545695073: Received PUBLISH from pod01 (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'UP/site01/pod01', ... (191 bytes))
1545695076: Received PUBLISH from pod01 (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'UP/site01/pod01', ... (190 bytes))
1545695079: Received PUBLISH from pod01 (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'UP/site01/pod01', ... (190 bytes))
1545695082: Received PUBLISH from pod01 (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'UP/site01/pod01', ... (191 bytes))
1545695083: Received PINGREQ from 8de7c6e8-4c6a-49b0-9aaa-5816aa9504901545604132782
1545695083: Sending PINGRESP to 8de7c6e8-4c6a-49b0-9aaa-5816aa9504901545604132782
1545695085: Received PUBLISH from pod01 (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'UP/site01/pod01', ... (189 bytes))
1545695089: Bridge ff001.cloudmqtt sending CONNECT
1545695089: Received CONNACK on connection local.ff001.cloudmqtt.
1545695089: Bridge local.ff001.cloudmqtt sending UNSUBSCRIBE (Mid: 12, Topic: UP/site1/#)
1545695089: Bridge local.ff001.cloudmqtt sending SUBSCRIBE (Mid: 13, Topic: Down/site1/#, QoS: 2)
1545695089: Bridge local.ff001.cloudmqtt doing local SUBSCRIBE on topic UP/site1/#
1545695089: Received UNSUBACK from local.ff001.cloudmqtt
1545695089: Received SUBACK from local.ff001.cloudmqtt
1545695090: No will message specified.
1545695090: Sending CONNACK to pod01 (0, 0)
1545695090: No will message specified.
1545695090: Sending CONNACK to 8de7c6e8-4c6a-49b0-9aaa-5816aa9504901545604132782 (0, 0)
1545695092: Received PUBLISH from pod01 (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'UP/site01/pod01', ... (190 bytes))
1545695095: Received PUBLISH from pod01 (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'UP/site01/pod01', ... (190 bytes))
1545695098: Received PUBLISH from pod01 (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'UP/site01/pod01', ... (191 bytes))
1545695100: Received PINGREQ from 8de7c6e8-4c6a-49b0-9aaa-5816aa9504901545604132782
1545695100: Sending PINGRESP to 8de7c6e8-4c6a-49b0-9aaa-5816aa9504901545604132782
1545695101: Received PUBLISH from pod01 (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'UP/site01/pod01', ... (191 bytes))
1545695104: Received PUBLISH from pod01 (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'UP/site01/pod01', ... (192 bytes))
1545695107: Received PUBLISH from pod01 (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'UP/site01/pod01', ... (191 bytes))
1545695110: Received PINGREQ from 8de7c6e8-4c6a-49b0-9aaa-5816aa9504901545604132782
1545695110: Sending PINGRESP to 8de7c6e8-4c6a-49b0-9aaa-5816aa9504901545604132782
1545695110: Received PUBLISH from pod01 (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'UP/site01/pod01', ... (191 bytes))
1545695113: Received PUBLISH from pod01 (d0, q0, r0, m0, 'UP/site01/pod01', ... (192 bytes))
```

I have `mosquitto_1.5.5`

If I remove out/in wildcard and replace it with `topic # both 2` it works. But I don't want to pull all remote topics, only specific to site (`Down/site1/#`) and push all local topics to remote. in above logs from bridge, looks like its not publishing local topics to remote cloudMQTT.

anyone know what I am missing here do I need to change anything on remote MQTT (cloudmqtt instance) ?

Comment: The first should work, edit the question to include the logs from mosquitto so we can see if there are any errors. Also include the rest of the bridge config (without the username/password)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting the bridge up with `UP/site1/#` and publishing to `UP/site01/...`

The problem is the `site1` != `site01`